# What is an elementary proof of the Weierstrass Factorization Theorem?

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, complex-analysis, proof-explanation, infinite-product

I was researching the gamma function and then I stumbled into this:
$$\Gamma(x)=\frac{e^{-\gamma x}}{x}\prod_{i\geq1}{\frac{e^{x/i}}{1+x/i}}$$
Turns out it's related to Weierstrass' Factorization Theorem. I've seen this before in:
$$\sin(x)=x(1-\frac{x}{\pi})(1+\frac{x}{\pi})(1-\frac{x}{2\pi})(1+\frac{x}{2\pi})\dotsb$$
Figured now would be a good time to understand this theorem. Someone please help with a derivation of the theorem as well as how it connects to the product for the Gamma function for someone who is an undergraduate freshman (currently doing multivariable). Thanks

Comment: See [this](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/76399/one-line-proof-of-the-eulers-reflection-formula). It implies $\phi(s) = \frac{\Gamma'(s)}{\Gamma(s)}+ \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{1}{s+n}-\frac{1}{n}$  is an entire and bounded function, [thus constant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liouville%27s_theorem_(complex_analysis)).

Comment: Impossible to explain if you have not taken complex analysis.

Comment: Yeah that's what I thought. What do you think of Needham's book "Visual Complex Analysis"?